# Different Revision Increment in one SVN Repository

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, increment, svn-repository

How to make a branch have different revision increment in one repository

**Example:**

```
Repo ----master
     |
     ----trunk
```

---

when i **commit** on *trunk* **5 times** and then **merge** it to *master*

**the result:**

```
Repo ----master (rev:1)
     |
     ----trunk (rev:5)
```

---

and then i **commit** on *trunk* **4 times** and then **merge** it to *master*

**the result:**

```
Repo ----master (rev:2)
     |
     ----trunk (rev:9)
```

---

can it be done in SVN?

Comment: Both folders are in the same repo, so you can not do that (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.basic.in-action.html): *Unlike most version control systems, Subversion's revision numbers apply to the entire repository tree*. What do you want to achieve with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. These revision numbers are an internal id for SVN to identify revisions. Even if you don't change the code at all, but only SVN-properties it get's it's own revision-number. SVN doesn't allow the user to set a revision number for a commit and frankly I don't see the need for this. If you want to make such counts, you have to do it independently from SVN.

Comment: I will change to Git hahaha. Thanks mate.

Comment: Not that you can set the revision id in git. :-) But it may have different upsides.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually times when this is desired.  For example, in document control, you may have a document with the global version of 19, but section 7 is on version 3.  When section 7 gets updated, it should update to version 4 and the global document to 20.  In the world I work in, auditors take a very dim view of sections of a document going from 3 to 20.

The answer (AFAIK) is to make each section its own project.